# How to retrieve the column index for every row that has a particular value in R?

Tags: r

I have the matrix below:

```
x=
1 0 1 1  
0 1 0 0  
1 0 0 0
```

I need to retrieve the following values (corresponding to column indices):

- In the first row, r1= "1","3" and "4".
- In the second row, r2= "2"
- In the third row, r3= "1"

My real data is a matrix of 300X66,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a logical index and use `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` to get row/column index.  It may be better to store it as such.  We could also `split` the 'indx' to a 'list'.

```
indx <- which(X!=0, arr.ind=TRUE)
split(indx[,2], indx[,1])
#$`1`
#[1] 1 3 4

#$`2`
#[1] 2

#$`3`
#[1] 1
```

Or use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`

```
apply(!!X, 1, which)
```

Comment: @mithila  be careful: if in the real case you want to find, say all instances of `7` in an array full of `1:10` values, you'll need to replace `!!X` with `X==7` or some such.

Comment: Thank you Carl, that could be of great help when needed.